# Android: are there any native/default animations available in android recource?

Tags: android, animation

I'm still a starter in Android. And i just wanna set the `fade_in` `fade_out` animations with my Fragments.

and i read the [android document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.animator.html), which shows that the `R.animator.fade_in` is available.

but in my Android Studio, when i typed in `R.animator`, it alerts that "cant resolve animator".

are there any native/default animations available in android recource?

Comment: If you give R.animator... it will be checking for the resource in your project. To use resources from android, you should use android.R.animator..

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use any resources provided by Android you have to prefix it with "android" to specify from which package to load it like this "android.R.anim.fade_in".

If you want to see all of the resources provided by Android, go to the location where your Android Studio is installed(or just locate the sdk folder if you downloaded a separate sdk folder like for eclipse) open the "sdk" folder, then open the "platform" folder, tgen select any platform versions, go to "res" folder, you can check out all of the built-in resources provided by the platform, it is really great and helpful to you to see how a particular resource is created, for example, you can open the "anim" folder, locate the "fade_out.xml" resource file and see how it is constructed. Hope this helps you a little

Answer (score 2):

You can set animation in android studio like this:

```
  Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_out); //Set your animation whether fade_out or fade_in

                anim.setDuration(200); //Duration of the animation
                yourObject.startAnimation(anim); //Tells it to start the animation
```